# Show hidden div with animation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show hidden div using animation,

The code i tried is,

```
$("#seconddiv").hide();

$("#seconddiv2").click(function(){
    $("#seconddiv").animate( { "opacity": "show", "top":"1000px"} , "slow" );  
});
```

Here div is appearing from no where.
But i want to, make div to appear as if it is moving down from top.

The code not working is,

```
$("#seconddiv2").click(function(){
    $("#seconddiv").show();
    $("#seconddiv").animate({top:'250px'},"slow");
});
```

Since the div is hidden animate function is not working.

What changes do i need to make it work?
please help
Thanks

Comment: you want the page to scroll down from top of the widow?

Comment: yes, i want to roll down the div from top. not scroll. It should look like as if it existed at top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your `#seconddiv` a relative or absolute positioning.

```
#seconddiv {
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cjtWX/1/

Changing the `top` on `static` positioned elements has not effect.

Comment: This works pretty good. but little problem is there, for the first time it works, when i click again it is not moving down. How can i reset it?

Comment: @ErmaIsabel It is very easy, just change your animation to `"top":"+=250px"`. See link: http://jsfiddle.net/cjtWX/2/

Comment: @ErmaIsabel Looks better if you place in your markup, the `seconddiv` after the `seconddiv2`. http://jsfiddle.net/cjtWX/5/

Comment: @ErmaIsabel Sorry, maybe I misunderstood what you meant by reset. If you want to reset it, just place `css('top', 0)` before the `animate` function. http://jsfiddle.net/cjtWX/6/

Comment: sorry, here the div is moving further down. I meant it should be back to its position and move down for the next click

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#seconddiv2").click(function() {      

   $("#seconddiv").animate({"top": "-=50px"}, "slow");   

});
```